# You might have mixed up default and named imports: Only using default imports

Tags: reactjs, api, import

I'm working on a React app using an API. I am trying to get the poster images to display, however I am getting this error: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

The error says the issue is likely with my import or export but I don't see how that would cause the issue.

Index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import '../assets/stylesheets/application.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MovieList from './components/MovieList';

import '../assets/stylesheets/application.scss';

const App = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([{
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
            "Year": "1977",
            "imdbID": "tt0076759",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzVlY2MwMjktM2E4OS00Y2Y3LWE3ZjctYzhkZGM3YzA1ZWM2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
            "Year": "1980",
            "imdbID": "tt0080684",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYmU1NDRjNDgtMzhiMi00NjZmLTg5NGItZDNiZjU5NTU4OTE0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
            "Year": "1983",
            "imdbID": "tt0086190",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWZlMjFiYzgtMTUzNC00Y2IzLTk1NTMtZmNhMTczNTk0ODk1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        }]);
  return (
    <div>
      <MovieList movies={movies} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

MovieList.js

```
import React from 'react';

const MovieList = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {props.movies.map((movie, index) => (
      <div>
        <img src={movie.Poster} alt='movie'></img>
      </div>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default MovieList;
```

I console.logged my MovieList and my function appears in my App.js so it seems to be importing correctly so something may be wrong with my App.js but I don't see any errors. I am only using default imports and exports, do I need to change them to a named variant?

Comment: did console.log(props.movies) in MovieList return anything?

Comment: I console logged it and it is now saying props is not defined. I tried to change it to this.props.movies but I am getting the same error.

Comment: you check your actual codes for spelling errors etc, this is a functional component so there is no "this". The above code looks fine to me, props should return object containing movies. You may want to share actual codes you have.

Comment: After searching it seems that many people are having this problem but there is no main solution. I changed my components to Component to { Component }, added file extensions from the export, checked my webpack.config, nothing. I have errors like "warning.js:33 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid" and "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined." Console logging my props shows its undefined somehow.

Comment: delete your node_module folder and npm install again.

Comment: I created a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-architecture-qw6r3?file=/src/App.js it's working fine.

Comment: and test without the css import

Comment: Uninstalled node-modules folder, uninstalled node and reinstalled it, reinstalled npm, still the same errors. I think the issue is my boilerplate even though I've used it before. The code works but something else is messing everything up. I'll keep poking around I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For me the code looks fine just correct two things in MovieList component

- in the map return add a unique key in the div
- replace `></img>` with `/>`

Comment: Is this issue fixed ?